# JBoss 7.1: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'jboss' MBeanServer found

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jmx, illegalstateexception, mbeans

My application is deployed on JBoss 7.1 (standalone).
I am getting an exception on the following line:

```
MBeanServerConnection server = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
```

The exception is:

```
JBoss: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'jboss' MBeanServer found!
```

That code above worked fine when the app was deployed on JBoss 5.

From what I was reading online, the code is supposed to work only when it's called from the same JVM in which the MBeanServer was created. Otherwise it's a remote call and I have to use JNDI. But is it not a local call (same JVM - i.e. the JBoss JVM)? How did it work on JBoss 5 then?
How do I make it work on JBoss 7.1 standalone, without changing this specific code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/221708

Quote:

Above problem is dueto locateJboss implementation that is compatible with older version of Jboss. The MBeanServer used by JBoss 7 (by default) is the platform MBeanServer. The class name iscom.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer and the default domain is DefaultDomain. Accordingly, you can simply use:

```
java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
```

Alternatively:

```
 for(MBeanServer server: javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null)) {

      if("DefaultDomain".equals(server.getDefaultDomain())) return server;

 }

 throw new Exception("Failed to locate MBeanServer");
```

On another note, jboss.system:type=ServerInfo object name doesn't work in AS 7.1 I had to use JVM specific parameters to nail down to MBean attributes. 'java.lang:type=Memory' and attribute as 'HeapMemoryUsage'.